# Mongodb lookup aggregation does not return relational data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use lookup aggregation in Mongodb to simulate join in Mongodb and return relational value. But it only returns value from the current collection and not from the collection related to it.

I have 2 collections called `wish_list` and `products` that are related. `wish_list` contains products that has been marked as wish list, and it contains product_id from the products collection.

The document of `wish_list` is like this:

```
"_id"
"product_id"
"user_id"
"created_at"
```

As you see, the `product_id` exists in this collection which is the `id` from `products` collection.

The problem is when I try to query data from `wish_list` and I want related data from that product in `products` collection. It only returns data from `wish_list` collection (Result from products collection is empty array).

Here is query that I execute:

```
db.wish_list.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    user_id: "crawler"}
  }, 
  {$lookup: {
    from: "wish_list", 
    localField: "product_id",
    foreignField: "id",
    as: "products"}
  }
])
```

and the result is this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a03024551195204432afcb6"),
    "product_id" : "com.thundanapps.thundpusthakam",
    "user_id" : "crawler",
    "created_at" : 1510146629,
    "products" : []
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0302565119520442375786"),
    "product_id" : "com.jott.android.jottmessenger",
    "user_id" : "crawler",
    "created_at" : 1510146646,
    "products" : []
}
```

P.S: I am pretty sure that the equivalent data exists in `products` collection.

P.S: The same problem exists when I try vice o versa (query from `products` collection to `with_list`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$lookup` is incorrect.
If you are aggregating on the collection `wish_list`
you have to say 
`from: "product"` not `from: "wish_list"`. Also make sure that the `foreignField` is maybe `_id` instead of `id`. If you are sure the field in `product` is `id` then your aggregation pipeline should look like this:

```
db.wish_list.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    user_id: "crawler"}
  }, 
  {$lookup: {
    from: "product", 
    localField: "product_id",
    foreignField: "id",
    as: "products"}
  }
])
```

In the `from` you want to add the collection you want to look into not the one you are already aggregating. Both `localField` and `foreignField` have to match with actual fields from both your collections. In `as` you can name the field as you like